# If modulus sign is used, can a value be negative?

Tags: absolute-value

|x-3|

If x is less than 3, will |x-3| be negative? I don't think so.

For example, if x=2, |x-3|= |2-3|=1.
x-3 can never be negative, I think.

In this [link](https://gmatclub.com/forum/what-is-the-sum-of-all-possible-solutions-to-x-3-2-x-219214.html), it has been said that when x<3, x-3 is negative, thus |x-3|=-(x-3).

[image]

I think this statement is totally wrong.

Please let me know what the correct is.

Comment: If $x$ is less than three then $x-3$ is negative, and $|x-3| = -(x-3)$ is positive. – What exactly do you think is “totally wrong”?

Comment: Just because something has a minus sign in front of it that doesn't make it "negative."

Comment: Also, just take a concrete case to see what's going on.  What's the absolute value of $-3$?  According to the definition, it is $-(-3)=3$, which is positive.

Answer (score 1):

$|x|$ is non-negative regardless of any sign. Absolute value is the distance of a number from $0$ and distance can never be negative!

Answer (score 0):

The statement is correct because if x is lesser than 3 , the x -3 is always negative and hence -(x-3) is always positive. And that is always equal to mod x-3